# true / false to Y/N Ex

Tags: javascript, checkbox, extjs, boolean

I am trying to change the `default` value sent from a `checkbox`. I have this code:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    header: 'Contacto de Emergencia',
    dataIndex: 'contactoEmergencia',
    listeners: {
        beforecheckchange: function() {
            return false;
        },
    },
    width: 100,
    flex: 1,
    editor: {
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        cls: 'x-grid-checkheader-editor',
        inputValue: 'Y',
        uncheckedValue: 'N'
    }
}
```

I am also set my model like:

```
{
    name: 'contactoEmergencia',
    mapping: 'CONTACTO_EMERGENCIA',
    convert: function(v) {
        return v === 'Y';
    },
    serialize: function(v) {
        return v ? 'Y' : 'N';
    }
},
```

But it's not working. The default value `true/false` does not change to `Y/N`.

Anyone knows why is not changing ? what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: A `checkcolumn` does only support boolean values, so there's nothing to do on the editor itself. The relevant part how you send the value is missing from your code - are you using store/model, and how does the send code look like?

Comment: if you are using `xtype: 'checkcolumn'`, then why you are using `editor` with it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code snippet:-

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'active'],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224',
        active: 'Y'
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234',
        active: 'Y'
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244',
        active: 'N'
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254',
        active: 'Y'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        editor: {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            cls: 'x-grid-checkheader-editor',
            inputValue: 1,
            uncheckedValue: 0
        },
        text: 'Active',
        dataIndex: 'active',
        renderer: function (value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            var tempVal = '',
                me = this;
            if (value === 'Y') {
                tempVal = 'checked';
            }
            return "<input name=" + record.get('id') + "_" + record.get('id') + " type='checkbox'" + tempVal + ">";
        }
    }],
    listeners: {
        cellclick: function (grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
            console.log(e);
            if (e.target.type && e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
                let checkVal = e.target.checked ? 'Y' : 'N';
                record.set('active', checkVal);
                console.log(record);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Also you can check [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fag) and on console you can check updated record.

Hope it help :)